# How to open/read an ENVI file in R

Tags: r, gis, spectral-density, envi

I'm new at using GIS with R and I'm trying to open an ENVI file containing hyperspectral data following the suggestions from this post [R how to read ENVI .hdr-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474186/r-how-to-read-envi-hdr-file), but I don't seem to be able to do so. I tried three different approaches but all of them failed. I also can't seem to find any other posts where my problem is described.

```
# install.packages("rgdal")
# install.packages("raster")
# install.packages("caTools")
library("rgdal")
library("raster")
library("caTools")

dirname <- "S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights"
filename <- file.path(dirname, "AISA_Flight_4_resampled")
file.exists(filename)
```

1. The first option that I tried was using file name only

```
    x <- read.ENVI(filename)
```

But I got the following error message:

```
#Error in read.ENVI(filename) :
#  read.ENVI: Could not open input file: S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights/AISA_Flight_4_resampled
#In addition: Warning message:
#  In nRow * nCol * nBand : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

2. I tried then the second option which is using file name + header file name read using *file.path*

```
    headerfile <- file.path(dirname, "AISA_Flight_4_resampled")
    x <- read.ENVI(filename = filename,headerfile = headerfile)
```

Again, I got an error message that says:

```
#Error in read.ENVI(filename = filename, headerfile = headerfile) :
#  read.ENVI: Could not open input header file: S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights/AISA_Flight_4_resampled
```

3. Finally, I tried the third option by using file name + header file name read using *readLines*

```
hdr_file <- readLines(con = "S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights/AISA_Flight_4_resampled.hdr")
x <- read.ENVI(filename = filename,headerfile = hdr_file)
```

But I got the error message:

```
#Error in read.ENVI(filename = filename, headerfile = hdr_file) :
#  read.ENVI: Could not open input header file: ENVIdescription = {  Spectrally Resampled File. Input number of bands: 63, output number of bands: 115. [Fri Jun 25 16:57:21 2021]}samples = 5187lines   = 6111bands   = 115header offset = 0file type = ENVI Standarddata type = 4interleave = bilsensor type = Unknownbyte order = 0map info = {UTM, 1.000, 1.000, 482828.358, 5029367.353, 7.5000000000e-001, 7.5000000000e-001, 15, North, WGS-84, units=Meters}coordinate system string = {PROJCS["UTM_Zone_15N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-93.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]}default bands = {46,31,16}wavelength units = Nanometersdata ignore value = -9999.00000000e+000band names = { Resampled
#    In addition: Warning message:
#      In if (!file.exists(headerfile)) stop("read.ENVI: Could not open input header file: ",  :
#                                              the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: So `file.exists(filename)` did return TRUE? On some systems having spaces in file paths can really cause a problem. Does the actual file not have a file extension? Maybe it should be `filename <- file.path(dirname, "AISA_Flight_4_resampled.hdr")`?

Comment: @MrFlick: Yes, `file.exists` returns TRUE. It still fails if I try `x <- read.ENVI(paste0(filename,".hdr"),headerfile)`  ... But the error becomes:
`Error in read.ENVI(paste0(filename, ".hdr"), headerfile) : 
  read.ENVI: Error in input header file S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights/AISA_Flight_4_resampled data sizes missing or incorrect-1-1-1
In addition: Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input`